# Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed in a Job using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to automate a process composed from multiple jobs. Every job had a goal, so I'm running a global job who is responsible for creating child jobs and add them to a batch instance.

```
# Instantiate the batches array
$batches = [];
# Retrieve destinations that have a dataset
$destinations = Destinations::where('dataset','like','%xx%')
                        ->where('dataset','like','%xx%')
                        ->get();
# Checking if there is some results
if(!empty($destinations)){
    foreach($destinations as $destination){
        # Current DateTime
        $dateTime = Carbon::now()->format('Y_m_d_h_i_s');
        # Create an array of batches for every location
        $batches[] = new AutoImport("auto_job_{$destination->reference}_{$dateTime}",$destination);
    }
}

# Creating batch chainning
$batch = Bus::batch($batches)
->then(function (Batch $batch) {

})->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
    
})->finally(function (Batch $batch) {

})->dispatch();

return $batch->id;
```

At some point I'm gettin this error `"Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed"` and I think is coming from this line `new AutoImport("auto_job_{$destination->reference}_{$dateTime}",$destination);` The fact that I send a whole object into the batches array

I'm not sure of that, so any help will be welcome.

Job abstract class

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Imtigger\LaravelJobStatus\Trackable;

abstract class Job implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queueable Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This job base class provides a central location to place any logic that
    | is shared across all of your jobs. The trait included with the class
    | provides access to the "queueOn" and "delay" queue helper methods.
    |
    */

    use Batchable,InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, Trackable;
}
```

Comment: That is correct, resources can't be serialized. You'd have to remove any resource from an object, before you can serialize it. Also check out magic methods `__sleep` and `__wakeup` for this purpose...

Comment: Where should I put them ? controller, jobs, model ?

Comment: Please read the documentation on how to implement these magic methods... they belong into the object you're trying to serialize.

Comment: Laravel jobs have a `use SerializesModels` trait if you plan to serialise models so if your job does not have that then you should put that

Comment: @apokryfos It is already the case, I've edited my qestion with the job abstract class

Comment: Then check either your `Destination` class or your `AutoImport` constructor in case you are storing anything else that is not serialisable.

Comment: @apokryfos there is nothing special that is not serialisable, it it just a simple object attributes, i've tried multiple solutiond, eg. I passe just the id of destination and instantiate it into the auto import job, but still getting the error